In proof of Theorem 10.28 in the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds ( First question, Question about interior conjugate points )
I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold book and stuck at understanding some statement.

Theorem 10.28. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Suppose $\gamma : [a,b] \to M$ is a unit-speed geodesic segment without interior conjugate points. If $V$ is any proper normal piecewise smooth vector field along $\gamma$, then $I(V,V) \ge 0$ ( index form of $\gamma$ ) with equality if and only if $V$ is a Jacobi field. In particular, if $\gamma(b)$ is not conjugate to $\gamma(a)$ along $\gamma$, then $I(V,V) >0$.

Proof. To simplifythe notation, we can assume (after replacing $t$ by $t-a$) that $a=0$. Let $p=\gamma(0)$, and let $(w_1, \dots , w_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $T_pM$. chosen so that $w_1=\gamma'(0)$. For each $\alpha=2, \dots,n$, let $J_{\alpha}$ be the unique normal Jacobi field along $\gamma$ satisfying $J_{\alpha}(0)=0$ and $D_t J_{\alpha}(0)=w_{\alpha}$.
Our assumption that $\gamma$ has no interior conjugate points guarantees that no linear combination of the $J_{\alpha}(t)$'s can vanish for any $t\in (0,b)$, and thus $(J_{\alpha}(t))$ forms a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\gamma'(t)$ in $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for each such $t$. (Next proof is omitted).
I don't understand the bold statement. Here relavent definitions are as follows :

Definition 1. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian manifold, $\gamma : I \to M$ a geodesic, and $p=\gamma(a)$, $q=\gamma(b)$ for some $a,b\in I$. We say that $p$ and $q$ are conjugate along $\gamma$ if there is a  Jacobi field along $\gamma$ vanishing at $t=a$ and $t=b$ but not identically zero.


Definition 2. Given a geodesic segment $\gamma : [a,c] \to M$, we say that $\gamma$ has a conjugate point if there is some $b\in (a,c]$ such that $\gamma(b)$ is conjugate to $\gamma(a)$ along $\gamma$, and $\gamma$ has an interior conjugate point if there is such $b\in(a,c)$.

To prove the bold statement, by contrary, assume that there exists $t\in (0,b)$ such that $a_1 J_2(t) + a_3 J_3(t) + \cdots + a_n J_n(t)=0 \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for some $a_2, a_3 , \dots , a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ which are  not identically zero. From this, can we make a jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ such that $J(0)=J(t)=0$ and $J$ is not identically zero ? If so, then $\gamma(t)$ is conjugate to $\gamma(0)$, which contradicts to the assumption that $\gamma$ has no interior conjugate points. Can anyone help?

The Jacobi field $a_2J_2+\cdots + a_nJ_n$ is nonzero, normal, and vanishes at both $0$ and the fixed instant $t$, meaning that $\gamma(t)$ is conjugate to $\gamma(0)$.

O.K. Thanks. And why $J := a_2 J_2 + \cdots + a_n J_n$ is nonzero ( not identically zero ) on $[0,t]$ ( key point) ? Assume that $a_2 J_2 + \cdots + a_n J_n \equiv 0$ on $[0,t]$. How can we deduce contradiction?

If it were zero then you would have $a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$ by linear independence.

Why the linear independence holds? :)

O.K. I think that is true by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235597/jacobi-fields-are-linearly-independent-if-and-only-if. How do you think about this?
